# How to reinstall dhcpcd without internet connection

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp

I deleted `dhcpcd` off my arch install without realizing it was the IP provider for wireless.

I need to get it re-installed, but I have no internet connection.

I deleted the unused cache files with `pacman -Sc` after uninstalling dhcpcd so I cannot reinstall from the cache.

I do have a flash drive with bootable Arch Linux that I used to install it originally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an Arch install disk, you can boot off it, mount your install partition and use pacstrap to install dhcpcd, similar to how you installed Arch in the first place.

e.g.

```
 mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
 pacstrap /mnt dhcpcd
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be it:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/dhcpcd-6.9.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

(Just take the newest one that is there)

This is the default place where pacman stores the `pkg.tar.gz` files.

Comment: This would work wonderfully normally. I did not know that was where the tar balls were so thank you. Unfortunately I deleted the unused cache items with `pacman -Sc`.